# How to convert csv to excel with components remain in int type

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

```
    r_csv = pd.read_csv(nowDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S") + ".csv")
    print(r_csv)
    save_xlsx = pd.ExcelWriter(nowDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S") + '.xlsx')
    r_csv.to_excel(save_xlsx, index = False)
    save_xlsx.save()
```

I am trying to convert .csv file to .xlsx file.
.csv file contains numbers:
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
...
but when I tried to convert it to .xlsx file they are read as word, not number. How can I get them as number to calculate them?
print(r_csv) shows result
0             103           1185  ...                0                0
1             104           1185  ...                0                0
2             105           1186  ...                0                1

Comment: Can you print out the data?

Comment: .csv file's data is like
111,1189,2355,2353,1189,1153,1142,1189,2355,2352,1189,1153,1142,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
112,1189,2355,2353,1189,1153,1141,1189,2355,2352,1189,1153,1141,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
113,1189,2355,2353,1189,1153,1142,1189,2355,2352,1189,1153,1142,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
114,1189,2355,2353,1189,1153,1142,1189,2355,2352,1189,1153,1142,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
115,1189,2356,2353,1189,1153,1142,1189,2356,2352,1189,1153,1142,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
and .xlsx file prints these out, but in form of string. So I couldn't use them to get the average.

Comment: Can you do print(r_csv) and add it to your question

Comment: Can you do print(r_csv.dtypes)

Comment: 21        object
1189      object
2354      object
2350      object
1188      object
1151      object
1140      object
1189.1    object
2354.1    object
2350.1    object
1188.1    object
1151.1    object
1140.1    object
0         object
0.1       object
0.2       object
0.3       object
0.4       object
0.5       object
dtype: object
these are the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command to convert the columns to numeric types, `r_csv = r_csv.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

If that doesn’t work, you have to do column by column,

`df["col"] = pd.to_numeric(df["col"])`